# Android Mapbox implementation in multiple fragment (Single activity)

Tags: android, fragment, mapbox

I am using Mapbox latest sdk in my application.
The map-view already in main_activity(single activity) in my application.
There are more than one fragment implemented in app.Each fragment has different map view. All fragment are in single activity.
How we can implement multiple maps?? As,I created it with fragments but,It is being transparent on fragments and It is like static image.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code and a screenshot, and explain how the behavior is different from what you want?